# JSON doesn't get parsed by MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, model-view-controller

I have the following C#:

Model:

```
namespace WebInventory.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PostbackList
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Field
        {
            public int ID;
            public string Name;
            public int DataTypeID;

            public bool Checked;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int TypeID;

        [DataMember]
        public IList<Field> Fields;

        [DataMember]
        public IList<IList<string>> Values;

        #region Non DataMember
        public IList<int> UsedFieldsID;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Controler:

```
public class ListController : JsonController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetList(PostbackList data)
    {
        <...>
    }
}
```

And I send the following JSon object:

```
{"TypeID":16,"Fields":[{"ID":42,"Name":"","DataTypeID":0,"Checked":true},{"ID":43,"Name":"","DataTypeID":0,"Checked":true},{"ID":44,"Name":"","DataTypeID":0,"Checked":true}],"Values":null}
```

using:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: 'POST'
        , dataType: 'json'
        , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        , data: JSON.stringify(parameter)
        , xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        fillTemplate(data);
    });
```

I set a breakpoint inside MVC `GetList` and there I see `data` is uninitialized. I tried using arrays instead of (I)List but it didn't help.

I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried making every field in `Fields` a separate object, something like this: `..."Fields[0]":{"ID":42,"Name":"","DataTypeID":0,"Checked":true}, "Fields[1]":...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use properties instead of fields.

I had the same issue recently where the model binder wasn't picking up my json.

I changed to properties instead.

```
public int ID {get; set;}
```

change all your fields to properties as below.

```
namespace WebInventory.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PostbackList
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Field
        {
            public int ID {get; set;}
            public string Name {get; set;}
            public int DataTypeID {get; set;}

            public bool Checked {get; set;}
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int TypeID {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        public IList<Field> Fields {get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        public IList<IList<string>> Values {get; set;}

        #region Non DataMember
        public IList<int> UsedFieldsID {get; set;}
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I'm completely aware of that, I can't figure how I forgot + overlooked this XD

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook It happens ... i ripped my hair out for hours :)